# How to use and call procedure in SQLite

Tags: android, database, sqlite

This is sample procedure.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS AddEdge; 
DELIMITER | 
CREATE PROCEDURE AddEdge(  
  pSourceName VARCHAR(20), pDestinationName VARCHAR(20), pValue INT  
) 
BEGIN 
  DECLARE vSourceID, vDestinationID, vEdgeID INT; 
  SET vSourceID = ( SELECT NodeID FROM nodes WHERE NodeName = pSourceName ); 
  IF vSourceID IS NULL THEN 
    BEGIN 
      INSERT INTO nodes (NodeName,Total) VALUES (pSourceName,0); 
      SET vSourceID = LAST_INSERT_ID(); 
    END; 
  END IF; 
  SET vDestinationID = ( SELECT NodeID FROM nodes WHERE NodeName = pDestinationName ); 
  IF vDestinationID IS NULL THEN 
    BEGIN 
      INSERT INTO nodes(NodeName, Total)  
      VALUES(pDestinationName,0); 
      SET vDestinationID = LAST_INSERT_ID(); 
    END; 
  END IF; 
  SET vEdgeID = ( SELECT EdgeID FROM edges  
                  WHERE sourceNodeID = vSourceID AND dID = vDestinationID  
                ); 
  IF vEdgeID IS NULL THEN 
    INSERT INTO edges(sourceNodeID,destinationNodeID,value)  
    VALUES(vSourceNodeID,vDestinationID,pValue); 
  ELSE 
    UPDATE edges SET value = pValue   
    WHERE sourceNodeID = vSourceID AND destinationNodeID = vDestinationID; 
  END IF; 
END;  
| 
DELIMITER
```

how can I use the above procedure in my database SQLite used in android ?
Actually i am new to handle databases in android i.e in SQLite.

thanks.

Comment: [SQLite really doesn't have stored procedures](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html). There's support for `TRIGGER`s but that's it. You're going to have to port that sproc to Java.

Comment: @Jens can you give me details or link that would help for above ?

Comment: how to use TRIGGERS using SQLite in Androids ?

Comment: @user1370786 Here is details of [Trigger_in_SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html), a [sample_project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/119293/Using-SQLite-Database-with-Android) and corresponding so post [sqlite-triggers-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743634/sqlite-triggers-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In order to achieve simplicity, SQLite has had to sacrifice other
>   characteristics that some people find useful, such as high
>   concurrency, fine-grained access control, a rich set of built-in
>   functions, stored procedures, esoteric SQL language features, XML
>   and/or Java extensions, tera- or peta-byte scalability, and so forth. -[sqlite.org](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html)

---

But here you can find some workaround : [Adding Stored Procedures to SQLite](http://chriswolf.heroku.com/articles/2011/01/26/adding-stored-procedures-to-sqlite)

Comment: Note, the workaround mentioned here won't really work *easily* on Android unless you're going to include a recompiled native library + a new JNI-wrapper for the entire sproc-capable sqlite (with all the problems associated with reimplementing classes that depend on the classes in the SDK). But, if you really need sprocs you can look into doing something similar to [SQLCipher](https://guardianproject.info/code/sqlcipher/).